# Add Chart as Control from separate class. Chart not drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I'm adding a chart as a control created in a separate class. The background of the chart paints, but the chart itself is not painting. Can someone point out where my error is? I've tried things like BringToFront, Anchoring, Dock.Fill, Invalidate.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ChartControl MyChart;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyChart = new ChartControl();
            this.Controls.Add(MyChart);
            MyChart.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1.4, 1.3);
            MyChart.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1.7, 1.9);
        }
    }
}
```

The Chart Class

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public class ChartControl : Chart
    {
        public Chart chart1;

        public ChartControl()
        {
            ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
            Legend legend1 = new Legend();
            Series series1 = new Series();
            chart1 = new Chart();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)chart1).BeginInit();
            SuspendLayout();
            chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            legend1.Name = "Legend1";
            chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
            chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            chart1.Name = "chart1";
            series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series1.Legend = "Legend1";
            series1.Name = "Series1";
            chart1.Series.Add(series1);
            chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            chart1.TabIndex = 0;
            chart1.Text = "chart1";

            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ChartControl`  is already a Chart. Why add another `public Chart chart1` which you use but can't actually show?? Remove it and replace `MyChart.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1.4, 1.3);` by `MyChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1.4, 1.3);` etc.. and `chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";` by `Name = "ChartArea1";` etc etc..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form that you're adding `MyChart` to has nothing to draw because you add all of your data to `MyChart.chart1`, which is an additional field you've created in the `ChartControl` class.

You're manipulating all the "chart" data in `chart1`, but all of the WinForm code to draw content is in the `Chart` class you're extending in `ChartControl`, which has no clue what `chart1` is (or that it even exists).

My guess is you're creating this type of "wrapper" class to apply a particular style to the chart. If that's the case you need to make sure you're directly manipulating `ChartControl` properties that are inherited from `Chart`, not creating custom properties or fields (unless you intend to override paint methods to make use of them).

Example constructor:

```
public ChartControl()
{
    ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
    Legend legend1 = new Legend();
    Series series1 = new Series();
    chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
    this.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
    this.Name = "chart1";
    series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
    series1.Legend = "Legend1";
    series1.Name = "Series1";
    this.Series.Add(series1);
    this.Text = "chart1";
}
```

As @TaW mentioned -- and I agree -- is not really a great design approach, but should work nonetheless (although I haven't tested this code).

Comment: Thanks Taw and @Aelarion for the clear explanation. You remediated my misconception of how the inheritance should work. Very appreciated!